# Android receiving image from c++ socket

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

New to android application: Need some help
I am trying to display the image that i have receive from my c++ socket. I am able to receive the image from my server socket and it is displaying the image that i have receive fine. But the emulator force closes after that and i have no idea why.

Android code

```
private  class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        int imageSize=921600;
        InputStream in;
        mRun = true;
        try{
            port1 = Integer.parseInt(port);
            client = new Socket(ip, port1);
            try{
                while(mRun){
                    in = client.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                    int remainingBytes = imageSize; //
                    while (remainingBytes > 0) {
                        int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                        if (bytesRead < 0) {
                            throw new IOException("Unexpected end of data");
                        }
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        remainingBytes -= bytesRead;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    imageByte = baos.toByteArray();   
                    baos.close();
                    int nrOfPixels = imageByte.length / 3; // Three bytes per pixel.
                    int pixels[] = new int[nrOfPixels];
                    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfPixels; i++) {
                        int r = imageByte[3*i];
                        int g = imageByte[3*i + 1];
                        int b = imageByte[3*i + 2];

                        if (r < 0) 
                            r = r + 256; 

                        if (g < 0) 
                            g = g + 256;

                        if (b < 0) 
                            b = b + 256;

                        pixels[i] = Color.rgb(b,g,r);
                    }
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, 640, 480,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    camera.invalidate();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){}
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {}
        catch (IOException e){}
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> emulator force closes after that and i have no idea why

Because `doInBackground` method run on background thread but you are trying to set bitmap for images from `doInBackground` here :

```
camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
camera.invalidate();
```

To update ImageView bitmap from main UI Thread use  [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) to call `setImageBitmap` and `invalidate` for ImageView because this method run on Main UI Thread when `doInBackground` method task is completed.

**OR**

Use `runOnUiThread` method to call `setImageBitmap` and  `invalidate` method from `doInBackground` :

```
      YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
              camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              camera.invalidate();
            }
      });
```